# How to use Sinatra database pooling

Tags: database, postgresql, connection, sinatra, lan

I'm having issues with PostgreSQL database  connections on my LAN.  In the future, I wish to have similar deployments where the database is on a different box on a subnet,  so I'm trying to optimize the pooling of database connections.

I'm using Sinatra, Passenger and nginx, and am currently using a database helper that provides the connections to the `localhost` and `192.168.x.x` databases:

```
$cl = PG::Connection.open( dbname: 'thisone' )
$cr = PG.connect( host: '192.168.1.50', dbname: 'thatone', user: 'foofoofoo', password: 'barbarbar' )
```

Sinatra uses `/tmp/alwaysrestart.txt` which restarts the application.  This restart increases time immensely and I'm using this to keep the application alive at the moment.  The database connection is the issue, as when this restart is turned off, the speed increases until the connection close-defaults,  then it throws a connection error.  I need this somewhere in my Sinatra structure:

```
$cl.finish if $cl
$cr.finish if $cr
```

Because the declaration of these global connections are done in a helper, they aren't visible in the main `app.rb`, so I can't put the `.finish` methods inside the `after` block inside `app.rb`.

I wonder how I can optimize pooling connections to multiple databases.

My questions are:

1. Am I forced to use new declarations for every connection, basically one per page?
2. Can I optimize somehow using `before` and `after`?  That would probably require a connection for every page, including static pages where there is no need, which seems  inefficient and messy.
3. Is there a way to pool these with some kind of timeout class?

I am using Sinatra sessions, if that means anything in this application.  Obviously I'd like to stick with the current stack of software choices.

Comment: You're abusing code-word formatting: Format code, variables, filenames, but don't use it for proper names of applications, such as repeated typing `\`Sinatra\``.

Comment: Also, rather than use the Pg driver, instead look into using an ORM such as ActiveRecord, which can be used outside of Rails, or Sequel. The flexibility and portability pay off.

Comment: @theTinManI get in trouble for not using them as well.  So I can't win.  I'll look into Datamapper.  I have it in my list from before, but like the PG gem.

Comment: The problem with using the Pg gem is you're writing code specifically for PgSQL. If you need to develop for any other DBM you'll have to start from scratch. An ORM, like Sequel, is agnostic and easily ports to SQLite3 in memory DBs to full-blown Oracle or Sybase with very minimal changes. Also, the Sequel author always writes for PgSQL so he picks up new features right away.

Comment: Ya I've bounced around and I didn't mind the `PG` gem because it was direct.  The ORM learning curves I found to be odd.

Comment: Just spent hours on DataMapper only to find it is years stagnant.  Always fun to chase that kind of dead wood.  Any suggestions before ActiveRecord?

Comment: If you're not using Rails then [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) is my favorite. It's extremely powerful, and the author is very responsive and knowledgeable. Play with the examples and it'll grow on you. You can use Sequel with Rails, but most people stick with ActiveRecord because that's the path of least Rails resistance. In my experience, Sequel generates excellent queries and we used it in production for many apps with no problems. And since it knows all about connection pooling you'll save yourself work.

Comment: Will have a look.  I am in Sinatra at the moment.  Thanks.

Comment: BTW, Sinatra has nothing to do with the database, it's a web-server and offers no database features. You have to use a DB driver and its associated interface, whether that's Pg or Sequel or ActiveRecord to talk to the DBM, so asking about "Sinatra database pooling" is very misleading and confusing. It's important to understand what features are added by the various components in your code.

Comment: Ya been using PG for years for several projects.  Until I had an internal "multiple async query page", I didn't know it would barf like this.  The reason I put that in there is because I'm looking for an encompassing package in the `Sinatra` world to have it all, including more than one db source. And I don't mind writing my own code, and I would __rather__ SQL.  A lot of documentation assumes devs would rather avoid it.

Comment: The issue with developers writing SQL is most of them don't write good SQL, whereas an ORM is able to sift through what they're programming and generate very good SQL from it. I used to distrust ORMs until I ran into Sequel and routed its output to a log to watch what it was doing, and it was generating exactly what I would. I used to manage and code a huge statistical DB in Oracle for a flagship factory at a Fortune 50 company, so I got pretty good, but Sequel made me a believer.

Comment: I can only see an ORM to be limiting.  Good SQL is the quickest way to hand the query off to the actual DB, which is the most powerful way to toss queries.  Secondary measures should be in place to test those joins, etc.  I'm a longtime FileMaker Pro dev.